# How to dynamically find the name and type of interfaces attached to a system

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, wifi, ethernet

I have a use case where I need to dynamically configure some files which includes the name of the interfaces present in system say `eth0` , `wlan0` . However when I change the system sometimes its changed to `eth1` or `wlan1` . From Ubuntu 14.04 the Ethernet interfaces are named as `p2p1` , `p1p1` like this and wireless interfaces as `wlan0` or `wlan1`.

So we can say the interfaces name can be anything, doesn't matter as long as we can find what names are given to what kind of interface .

I wrote a small script for that but I don't know if there could be a better way to find this which works across all the Linux based system .

```
#!/bin/bash

# check if directory exist 
DIRECTORY=/sys/class/net
wifi_interface=""
lan_interface=""
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    cd $DIRECTORY

    ilist=`ifconfig -s  | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +2`

    # array length
    ilist_len=`echo "${ilist[@]}" | wc -l`

    # empty array 
    il=

    # Iterating over interfaces 
    for i in $(seq 1 $ilist_len)
    do 
        iname=`echo $ilist | sed -n "$i"p`
        echo $iname
        if [ "$iname" != "lo" ]; then
            cur_dir=$DIRECTORY/$iname
            cd $cur_dir
            if [ -d "$cur_dir/wireless" ]; then
                wifi_interface=$iname
            else 
                lan_interface=$iname
            fi
        fi
        pwd
        cd ~
    done
    exit 0
else
    echo "Can't find the directories ! Something went wrong "
    exit 0
fi
```

In the above script I decided the interfaces type based on the presence or absence of directory `/sys/class/net/<INTERFACE>/wireless`. The script assumes that only 1-1 interface is present for Ethernet and wireless.

I doubt that the `wireless` directory is always present in all of the wireless interfaces . For example in case of virtual wireless interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today, for a relatively modern Linux distro I would initially try to use the ip command

```
ip link show
```

and then filter it's output to get a list of interfaces.

You can also use `ifconfig -a`  but newer releases of some distros are nolonger installing this by default.

Similarly `netstat -i` may be useful.

You can use the `iwconfig` command to determine if an interface is wireless or not

```
iwconfig ens160
ens160    no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: How would `ip link show` would work . It ofcourse gives the names of interfaces but none of `ip` or `ifconfig -a` or `netstat -i` would give the information using which I can detect which is the ethernet interface and which is wireless

Comment: In short given three interfaces names how can i know which is the lan interface and which is wireless interface

Comment: read my answer again, it looks like I updated it while you were writing your comment.

Comment: Super. That would work . All I need to do is instead checking the directory in my script would check using `iwconfig` command

Comment: Like `ifconfig`, `netstat` might also not be installed. And `netstat -i` output might be truncated, so you can't really use it reliably anyway. Try `ip -s link` instead.

Comment: Isn't that much the same as `ip link show` ?

Comment: `-s` causes it to include the statistics. I'm sure you have a Linux box nearby; compare the output of `ip link` to `ip -s link`.

Comment: I'm clearly missing something - why are we caring about the statistics ?

Comment: Michael, my question was initially different . `ip link show` no doubt will show all the interfaces but how would you decide that the interface name you got say `p2p1` is a lan interface or wireless one